# Passing the content of an external .xml file and preserve the styling tags

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I am currently passing the content of an external .xml file as a paramter using:

```
<xsl:param name="content" select="'content'" />
<p>
<xsl:variable name="getContent" select="document($content)/div" />
<xsl:value-of select="$getContent" />
</p>
```

And this file is fed as an input during built:

```
<param name="content" expression="input/readThisFile.xml" />
```

In this external readThisFile.xml, there are certain phrases enclosed with bold tags . I would like to preserve the styling, however when the content is passed into XSLT and output as .html, this styling is lost.

Any suggestion?

Comment: **1** Most often, things are "lost" because the program is designed to lose them. Please show an entire XSLT stylesheet. **2** Your second parameter is not prefixed with `xsl:`, is this a typo? If it's not, then `param` is just a literal element that happens to be called "param".

Comment: @MathiasMüller: I think it is syntax for his build system, it uses `@expression`, instead of `@select`, and the `document($content)` suggests that the actual value is an actual uri.

Comment: @Abel You're right, I decided too quickly that the second code snippet should be XSLT code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *[...] this styling is lost.*

What you write is that you want to preserve the styling. But all you are doing in the snippet you are showing, is that you take the *value of* the div-element. A *value of* is exactly that: the (string) value of the content of the element and all its children.

Change `xsl:value-of` into `xsl:copy-of`, which will preserve the elements, or do actual processing with a [copy idiom](https://www.google.com/search?q=copy%20idiom%20xslt) if you need to process the content further (i.e., to filter for certain elements).